Keras not showing the correct f1_score
I am using the following dataset from Kaggle Ships in Satellite Imagery
The code i am using is:
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
from keras.applications import ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

IMG_PATH = "/kaggle/input/ships-in-satellite-imagery/shipsnet/shipsnet"
IMG_WIDTH = 80
IMG_HEIGHT = 80
CHANNELS = 3

X_train = []
y_train = []
y_train_bbox = []
for file in os.listdir(IMG_PATH)[:3000]:
    img_annotations = os.path.splitext(file)[0].split('_')
    label = int(img_annotations[0])
    longitude = float(img_annotations[-2])
    latitude = float(img_annotations[-1])
    img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(IMG_PATH, file))
    X_train.append(img)
    y_train.append(label)
    y_train_bbox.append(np.array([longitude, latitude]))
X_train = np.array(X_train)
y_train = np.array(y_train).reshape(-1,1)
y_train_bbox = np.array(y_train_bbox)

X_train = []
y_train = []
y_train_bbox = []
for file in os.listdir(IMG_PATH)[:3000]:
    img_annotations = os.path.splitext(file)[0].split('_')
    label = int(img_annotations[0])
    longitude = float(img_annotations[-2])
    latitude = float(img_annotations[-1])
    img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(IMG_PATH, file))
    X_train.append(img)
    y_train.append(label)
    y_train_bbox.append(np.array([longitude, latitude]))
X_train = np.array(X_train)
y_train = np.array(y_train).reshape(-1,1)
y_train_bbox = np.array(y_train_bbox)

base_model = ResNet50(input_tensor=Input(shape=(80, 80, 3)), include_top=False)

head_model = base_model.output
head_model = Flatten()(head_model)
head_model = Dense(128, 'relu')(head_model)
head_model = Dense(64, 'relu')(head_model)
head_model = Dense(32, 'relu')(head_model)
head_model = Dense(16, 'relu')(head_model)
head_model = Dense(8, 'relu')(head_model)
head_model = Dense(1, 'sigmoid')(head_model)

model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=head_model)
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
    
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=[
    "precision", "recall", "f1_score", "true_positives", "false_positives", "true_negatives", "false_negatives"
])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=len(X_train), epochs=3)

And the results from the fit are:
Epoch 1/3
1/1 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 41s 41s/step - f1_score: 0.4017 - false_negatives: 197.0000 - false_positives: 1913.0000 - loss: 0.7405 - precision: 0.2255 - recall: 0.7387 - true_negatives: 333.0000 - true_positives: 557.0000
Epoch 2/3
1/1 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 31s 31s/step - f1_score: 0.4017 - false_negatives: 195.0000 - false_positives: 42.0000 - loss: 0.2302 - precision: 0.9301 - recall: 0.7414 - true_negatives: 2204.0000 - true_positives: 559.0000
Epoch 3/3
1/1 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 41s 41s/step - f1_score: 0.4017 - false_negatives: 0.0000e+00 - false_positives: 1424.0000 - loss: 1.2052 - precision: 0.3462 - recall: 1.0000 - true_negatives: 822.0000 - true_positives: 754.0000

Why is the f1_score wrong despite the precision and recall being correct ?

I know Keras averages the results during training based on batch size, however the batch size here is the same as the length of the training dataset.


Hi,I have reviewed your code and reproduced it in my notebook. Initially,
I observed similar results where the F1 score remained stagnant, as you mentioned.
However, I made some adjustments by specifying a fixed batch size instead of
using the entire image dataset at once. Additionally, I increased the number
of epochs. With these changes, I noticed that the F1 score began to
fluctuate with each epoch."Please refer this gist
